# Minimum OS partition size

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, partition, dell-poweredge

I have a refurbished Dell Power edge R710 with PERS 6 running a new install of Server 2008 R2 with all current updates installed.  The server manager shows a reserved 100mb partition and a 2047 GB partition as C: with 1676 GB unallocated. I have seen posts where 15 to 25 GB is left in C Drive for the OS, but the server manager on this system shows 47GB as smallest value after shrink. I also realize there will be growth as updates are installed. 
What is a reasonable size for C: drive for the OS?  I plan to take the remaining space and combine it with the unallocated area for a D: drive for files.  This is to be a file server only.

Answer (score 4):

There is no right answer here. You should estimate how much space you will need for growth and plan accordingly. For example, you're deploying 2008 R2, which is already 7 years old. So you should factor in enough space for an in-place upgrade to a more modern OS. Also, you'll want to factor in the page file size and whether or not you want full crash dumps.

Personally, I wouldn't deploy anything smaller than a 120GB OS volume. Storage is cheap, your time to shuffle data around when you unexpectedly run full-disk is not.